# How is my angle of attack determined?

Tags: diablo-iii

As a Wizard building primarily around Disintegrate, I've noticed that the game often corrects the beam of my death lazer to cause appropriate amounts of death, typically when there are ramps and stairs around me.

On occasion, this has bitten me in the hiney - I'll notice that my death lazer is shooting *the ground,* and not the **titanic monster making attempts on my life.**

The horizontal angle of attack is a straight line between your character a cursor - that much is obvious. But how does the game determine the vertical angle of an attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In general* vertical targeting is determined by the ground directly beneath your cursor, but this can be influenced by auto-correction if your cursor is very close to or over a monster on another elevation. If you're in an area with a lot of changes in height, consider targeting your rays by placing your cursor directly in front of you, or in clear space on the same elevation if a monster in front of you is causing your rays to fire at a poor angle.